# Elif-row without else python

Tags: python, if-statement

Is it possible to write an `else` at the end of an `if`-row which only gets executed if none of all the `if` statements are true? Example:

```
if foo==5:
    pass
if bar==5:
    pass
if foobar==5:
    pass
else:
    pass
```

In this example, the else part gets executed if `foobar` isn't 5, but I want it to be executed if `foo`, `bar` and `foobar` aren't 5. (But, if all statements are true, all of them have to be executed.)

Comment: Are the condition overlapping? I.e. could more than one be true at the same time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the `else` should only be executed if all of them are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any overly elegant way to do this in Python or any other language. You could store the values in a list but that would obfuscate the actual test ifs, e.g.

```
tests = [bar ==4, foo == 6, foobar == 8]

if tests[0] :
  # do a thing
if tests[1] :
  # Make a happy cheesecake
if tests[2] :
  # Oh, that's sad

if not True in tests :
  # Invade Paris
```

Or you could set a tracking flag

```
wereAnyTrue = False

if foo == 4 :
  # Do the washing
  wereAnyTrue = True
if bar == 6 :
  # Buy flowers for girlfriend
  wereAnyTrue = True

# ... etc

if not wereAnyTrue :
  # Eat pizza in underpants
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use this solution since I'm able to find out wheter something was `true` or not anyways. I just thought - maybe python has it's own, easier way of doing it... :)

Answer (score 5):

How about doing something like this? Making four if statements but the fourth if statement won't be run if one of the other three is run because the other statements change the variable `key`

```
key = True

if foo == 5:
    key = False
if bar == 5:
    key = False
if foobar == 5:
    key = False
if key:
    pass # this would then be your else statement
```

Comment: At least use a boolean for `key1`!

Answer (score 2):

Not directly - those three `if` blocks are separate. You could use nesting, but that would get pretty complex; the neatest way to accomplish this is probably:

```
if foo == 5:
    ...
if bar == 5:
    ...
if foobar == 5:
    ...
if not any((foo == 5, bar == 5, foobar == 5)):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - but I my statements aren't always 5... :/

Comment: @user3424423 perhaps you should have used a clearer example. Nonetheless, `any` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

If all the `if` statements are for checking for the same value, I would use the following format instead. It would make the code shorter and more readable, IMO

```
if 5 in (foo, bar, foobar):
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation of jonrsharpe's answer would be using chained equality tests. Like so:

```
if foo != bar != foobar != 5:
    #gets executed if foo, bar and foobar are all not equal to 5
```

Looks a bit funny, I guess it's up to you to decide which one is more readable. And, obviously, this won't work if one of those variables is supposed to be equal to something different.

**Edit:** whoops, this won't work. For example
`1 != 1 != 3 != 5`
returns false, while
`1 != 2 != 3 != 5`
return true. Sorry