# How may I define more option in my question?

Tags: python

```
a1=str(input("4.Name one neighbouring country of India."))
if a1.lower()== ("pakistan"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("china"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("nepal"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("bhutan"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("bangladesh"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20    
if a1.lower()== ("myanmar"):                 
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("sri lanka"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
if a1.lower()== ("maldivs"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20    
else:
    print("incorrect +0 Score")
```

I made this cause my question contains 8 answers but in output, it prints both "correct +20 Score" and "incorrect +0 Score". I want to fix it Please help me.

Comment: You have a sort of XY problem. What you are asking is something like [Elif-row without else python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24230930/2745495), which isn't an elegant solution (IMHO). What you should be asking instead is how to [Testing user input against a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3944655/2745495).

Comment: Though this is not a comment related to answer but just wanted to say it's `Maldives` not `Maldivs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `else` statements when comparing, not multiple `ifs`. If you need multiple `ifs` you should use `elif`.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

However, it would be much more clear and concise to store your answers in a list and check if the users response exists in the list, else no score.

```
neighbouring = ['pakistan', 'china', 'nepal', 'bhutan', 'bangladesh', 'myanmar', 'sri lanka', 'maldivs']

a1=str(input("4.Name one neighbouring country of India."))

if a1.lower() in neighbouring:
    print('correct 20 score')
    score += 20
else:
    print('incorrect')
```

Comment: That does not illustrate where the OP did the mistake. For sure that is the way to do tho.

Comment: I'd recommend using a `set` instead of a list though. Looking up membership in lists runs in O(n) whereas looking up members is sets runs in O(1).

Comment: @RichardNeumann set creation is O(n) anyways so it doesn't really matter for this use case

Answer (score 0):

Using a better data structure can save you from code reuse. Here is my suggestion

```
score = 0
questions = [
    {'''...'''},
    {'''...'''},
    {'''...'''},
    {
        "text": "Name one neighboring country of India.",
        "answers": [
            "pakistan",
            "china",
            "nepal",
            "bhutan",
            "bangladesh",
            "myanmar",
            "sri lanka",
            "maldivs"
        ],
        "points": 20
    },
]

# for idx, question in enumerate(questions):
idx, question = 3, questions[3]
user_answer = str(input(f"{idx + 1}. " + question['text'])).lower()
if user_answer in question["answers"]:
    pnt_gain = question["points"]
    score += pnt_gain
    print(f"correct +{pnt_gain} Score")
else:
    print("incorrect +0 Score")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a1=str(input("4.Name one neighbouring country of India."))
if a1.lower()== ("pakistan"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("china"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("nepal"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("bhutan"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("bangladesh"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20    
elif a1.lower()== ("myanmar"):                 
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("sri lanka"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20
elif a1.lower()== ("maldivs"):                  
    print("correct +20 Score")
    score+=20    
else:
    print("incorrect +0 Score")
```

You need to use the `if elif else` syntax.

Otherwise you create independent `if`statement. So if one on top is satisfied, the last one which includes the `else` won't. So you'll get the `else`.